# kotlin https request timeout using ktor httpclient suggestions

Tags: kotlin, flask, https, ktor

i have an app that is being used in many places across my country and it comunicated with a flask server (deployed on apache).
sometimes the reception is not so good in areas of my  country. my users sometimes fetching/sending data to the server, but its loading too much time and then its fails/ stuck. i think somthing is lost in the comunication between the app and the server. also, it happend from 6:am in the morning where i guess there are more activity/load on the server
what is the best configuration to apply in this case for the http request:
this is what i use.

```
requestTimeoutMillis = 15000 
connectTimeoutMillis = 10000
socketTimeoutMillis = 10000
```

further more, if anybody have a suggestion for a protocol that can "hide" this behevior from the user. they tell me that if its stuck, they going to surf on some website like facebook, go back to the app, then try to press the send button again and its working.

thanks

Comment: What behavior do you want to "hide" if your users interact only with UI?

Comment: well i thought somthing like offline mode, maybe decrease connection time for https request and make 3 tries... stuff like that that somebody encounterd similarly to my situation

Comment: You can tune a connection time limit and use the HttpRequestRetry plugin to retry failed requests https://ktor.io/docs/client-retry.html.